# Bootstrap carousel image slide goes up error

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Let's say I have 10 images carousel slider. When I click on second slide dots navigation one slide goes up and next slide comes in view. If I click on number 9 slide dots navigation still One slide will go up and next slide will come in view.

Why is this happening?

This is my code:

```
<div id="main" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#main" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#main" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#main" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                        <li data-target="#main" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                    </ul>


                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

                        <!--item 01-->
                        <div class="item active">
                            <img src="./img/ca01.jpg" alt="maincarouselimg01" title="ca01.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <!--item 02-->
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="./img/ca02.jpg" alt="maincarouselimg02" title="ca02.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <!--item 03-->
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="./img/ca03.jpg" alt="maincarouselimg03" title="ca03.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <!--item 04-->
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="./img/ca04.jpg" alt="maincarouselimg04" title="ca04.jpg">
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works just fine!

```css
.item { width:100%; height:755px; overflow:hidden; } .item img { width:100%; height:100%; } .carousel-indicators { bottom:-6px; } #main .carousel-indicators li { background-color: #000; } #main .carousel-indicators .active { background-color: #808080; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="main" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#main" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#main" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#main" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                        <li data-target="#main" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                    </ul>


                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

                        <!--item 01-->
                        <div class="item active">
                            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg" alt="maincarouselimg01" title="ca01.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <!--item 02-->
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ny.jpg" alt="maincarouselimg02" title="ca02.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <!--item 03-->
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/chicago.jpg" alt="maincarouselimg03" title="ca03.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <!--item 04-->
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ny.jpg" alt="maincarouselimg04" title="ca04.jpg">
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a problem with my css? On my monitor, it keeps going up :(

Comment: Seems like that!

Comment: Can I have a look at my css?

Comment: Show me more from you css.

Comment: .item { width:100%; height:755px; overflow:hidden; }
                                    .item img { width:100%; height:100%; }
                                .carousel-indicators { bottom:-6px; }
                                .carousel-indicators li { background-color: #000; }
                                .carousel-indicators .active { background-color: #808080; }

Comment: Your item class height is problem! Do you need your carousel height to be 755px?

Comment: The image has a width of 770 pixels and a height of 694, but there are other divs on the top, so if you do not give a height to the section and class, the footer will come up.

Comment: I add your style there, can you be more specific what do you need, check out changes!